# How an when Bootstrap 4 and Jquery add event listener in my nav-link?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, navbar, event-listener

I have a navigation bar in Bootstrap 4. It's fully functioning.
Now, I'm trying to reproduce that bar in another place of my code. And only one of the two items works !
I have tried to understand, and, suddenly I founded that, on the one that works, at the end of the line, with the Code Inspector, there is a box saying "event" : I don't know what that means and the non-working line of code doesn't have it !
And I don't find any difference in the code, css... :

```
    Case 1  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Equipes</a>

    whithout event

    Case 2  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Utilisateur : {{ app.user.prenomNom }}</a>

    with an event !
```

And only the line with the event works...

So, what added that event listener, and how can I reproduce it

Comment: I have verified my Bootstrap : it's up to date,  4.6, with Popper.js and Js

Answer (score 0):

I've understood my issue :
In my complete code, I had a logo, placed relatively, and in the initial place of this logo, it was over my links, and hid them !